Transforming a table
I have a problem with a table format and would like to transform it, with bash, R or Python.
This is what I have :



Obs1






Name  X



Age  99






Obs2






Name  X1



Age  99



What I want :



Column A
Name
Age




Obs1
X
99


Obs2
X1
99



Could you help please ?
Thank you very much !
I need to transform a table to useful for statistics from many lines per observations to many columns per one observation.
